# Why does my scroll reverse in Telegram desktop application?

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, chromebook

I have reverse(Australian) scrolling on my laptop which works fine. However, when I open Telegram(only happens in Telegram), it suddenly shifts back to normal.

Every other application is as it's supposed to be, it's only inside the Telegram window?

Lubuntu 14.04, LXDE on a chromebook through Crouton

Comment: Same problem Ubuntu 16.04, official telegram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on a new installation of Ubuntu 17.04.
I solved it by using dconf-editor to set `org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/natural-scroll` to `true`.

Now it's working in Telegram like in all other applications.